# Order of destruction for stack/heap allocated arrays

Tags: c++

Considering following code:

```
struct A{...};

A a[100];
A* pa = new A[100];
delete[] pa;
```

Is the order of destruction for the elements of `a`/`pa` defined by the standard or it is implementation defined (for the second case `operator delete[]` is not user defined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array elements will be destructed in reverse order of construction, with element `99` being the first destructed, then element `98`, `97`, `96`... etc. and element `0` being the last.

See the [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#order-dtors-for-arrays) destructor FAQ.

From 5.3.5.6 of the latest draft:

> If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is not a null pointer value, the delete-expression will
>   invoke the destructor (if any) for the object or the elements of the array being deleted. **In the case of an
>   array, the elements will be destroyed in order of decreasing address (that is, in reverse order of the completion
>   of their constructor**; see 12.6.2).

There's also this from 12.6.3 (which is not specific to the `delete` keyword):

> When an array of class objects is initialized (either explicitly or implicitly) and the elements are initialized
>   by constructor, the constructor shall be called for each element of the array, following the subscript order;
>   see 8.3.4. [ **Note: Destructors for the array elements are called in reverse order of their construction. — end
>   note** ]